# Writing Likelihood of Poisson in R

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, likelihood

Here is my attempt to make the likelihood function for Poisson distribution for data `x` and parameter `theta` in R:

```
exp(-length(x)*theta)*((theta*sum(x))/(prod(factorial(x))))
```

Does this look okay?

Comment: This implementation is likely to get (avoidable) overflow or underflow problems in very large samples or with sufficiently large x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?dpois` which does this already with options for both the likelihood and log-likelihood.

Since the Poisson PMF is: $$e^{-\theta}\frac{\theta^x}{x!}\quad\text{using OP's notation}$$ The correct syntax would be:

```R
exp(-theta) * theta ^ x / gamma(x + 1) # use prod() for product
```

The log-likelihood would be: $- \theta +x \ln\theta - \ln x!$

With syntax:

```R
- theta + x * log(theta) - lgamma(x + 1) # use sum() for sum
```

---

**EDIT**: Modified `factorial(x)` to `gamma(x + 1)` and `log(factorial(x))` to `lgamma(x + 1)` thanks to comment below. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html).

Comment: Instead of `log(factorial(x))` it is numerically more stable to use `lgamma(x + 1)`.